# How to install a PECL package with composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, pear, pecl

I wish to install a PEAR package (specifically, the mongodb from pecl.php.net) with Composer.

I can install a package from the main 'pear' channel with the following composer.json:

```
{ "repositories": [{
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "https://pear.php.net"
        }],
    "require": { "pear-pear/http": "*" }
}
```

*(note: an original example from https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#pear is not working)*

But I'm getting:

> The requested package pear-pecl/mongodb could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name

...when I try to set 'pecl' channel:

```
"require": { "pear-pecl/mongodb": "*" }
```

I can see the pecl channel with `pear list-channels`:

```
$ pear list-channels
Registered Channels:
====================
Channel      Alias   Summary
doc.php.net  phpdocs PHP Documentation team
pear.php.net pear    PHP Extension and Application
                     Repository
pecl.php.net pecl    PHP Extension Community Library
```

I can install the same package with `pear install pecl/mongodb`.

Answer (score 2):

`pecl/mongodb` is a binary driver. I can't see how composer could be able to install it locally to a project. I don't think you'll be able to install any PECL extension through composer.

Composer can manage PHP dependencies for a project, and those dependencies need to include a valid `composer.json` file to be able to be identified as a package.

If you check the [pecl/mongodb repo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver), you'll see no such thing. It's a C language project that needs to be compiled and installed as runtime extension.

PECL extensions are not meant to installed on a project, nor makes sense to do so; but need to installed and enabled for the PHP runtime. When you run `pear install pecl/mongodb` you are installing the binary extension for all projects using the same runtime.

Comment: So Composer is intended only for project-local packages, and PEAR is a mix of pure PHP and C packages, both of which installed system-wide? It sounds weird.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. But PEAR and PECL predate Composer. You can install some packages globally with composer (see `--global`). You can even install non-PHP files if the it's a valid package (e.g. has a `composer.json` definition). But PECL extensions are binary, to be installed at runtime level. Composer can't help you there. And do not have a `composer.json` file anyway, so compose does not consider them "packages".

Answer (score 0):

PECL packages can not be installed with Composer due pecl.php.net repository is broken (see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76719 and related tickets).

It can be added to composer.json with

```
{ "repositories": [
        {   "type": "pear",
            "url": "https://pecl.php.net"
        }],
    "require": {
       "pear-pecl/mongodb": "*"
    }}
```

but installation fails due broken XML in https://pecl.php.net/rest/c/Authentication/packagesinfo.xml